# Accessing Event Handlers from Two Different Master Pages

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, master-pages

I have a ASP.NET content page where the master page is set dynamically. Both master pages contain a print button and an associated event handler for the click event of the button. Unfortunately I receive a run-time error when I attempt to dynamically access the event from the master page that was not initially assigned.

Below are code snippets:

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Evaluators/masEvaluators.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
      CodeFile="EDF_Instructions.aspx.vb" Inherits="Evaluators_EDF_Instructions" Title="EDF - Instructions" %>


    Page_Load():
      Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim strPageTitle As String = "Evaluator Data Form - Instructions"

        If Page.MasterPageFile.Contains("masEvaluators.master") Then
          Dim mp As Evaluators_masEvaluators = CType(Me.Master, Evaluators_masEvaluators)
          AddHandler mp.SaveEDF, AddressOf imgbtnPrint_Click

        ElseIf Page.MasterPageFile.Contains("masStaff.master") Then
          Dim mp As Evaluators_masEvaluators = CType(Me.Master, Evaluators_masEvaluators)
          CType(Page.Master.FindControl("imgbtnPrint"), ImageButton).Visible = True

          AddHandler mp.SaveEDF, AddressOf imgbtnPrint_Click
        End If
```

which produces the following error when I load the page and reference the "masStaff.master" master page:

`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.staff_masstaff_master' to type 'Evaluators_masEvaluators'. at Evaluators_EDF_Instructions.Page_Load....`

I can solve the problem by adding a print button to the content page, but that defeats the purpose of using a master page.

Is there a solution to this problem? I have spent many hours researching this issue on the web, but have not found a solution as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you cast the master page in the ElseIf to something like `staff_masstaff_master`

So like this :

```
If Page.MasterPageFile.Contains("masEvaluators.master") Then
  Dim mp As Evaluators_masEvaluators = CType(Me.Master, Evaluators_masEvaluators)
  AddHandler mp.SaveEDF, AddressOf imgbtnPrint_Click

ElseIf Page.MasterPageFile.Contains("masStaff.master") Then
  Dim mp As **Staff_masStaff** = CType(Me.Master, **Staff_masStaff**)
    CType(Page.Master.FindControl("imgbtnPrint"), ImageButton).Visible = True

  AddHandler mp.SaveEDF, AddressOf imgbtnPrint_Click
End If
```

you might also import the namespace where `Staff_masStaff` is defined.

Comment: Skyp,"Staff_masStaff" is the name of the class for the "masStaff" master page. "masStaff.master" is in a different folder than the "masEvaluators.master" page.

Comment: I edited my reply so that the type of the "staff" master page is correct (I could only guess it).

Comment: Skyp, I am unfamiliar with the "**" construct. What does it do? Thanks!

Comment: Brian, I added the ** in front and after the things I changed in your code so that you could see them easier, you can remove them of course ;)

Comment: Skyp, Thanks for correcting my typo in my original question. The code should read " ElseIf Page.MasterPageFile.Contains("masStaff.master") Then
      Dim mp As Staff_masStaff = CType(Me.Master, Staff_masStaff)". A compilation error now results. This error occurs even with "Imports Staff_masStaff" at the top of the page. Any other ideas. Thanks!